# How to make a detailed table with lots of entries?

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to create tables that will hold lots of entries (its a bus schedule).

I will need to be able to set the color of certain individual cells. And I would obviously want it to play nice with all kind of phone screen sizes.

So the questions are:

1. How do I go about creating this table?
2. What is the best approach for my need?

This is one the tables with the data that I need to make:

[image: Image with table of data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating and styling the tables in Excel and exporting them as HTMLs. Then I just loaded them in a webview.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use a ListView for this. Here is a nice tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html